# Intermediary model not showing up in admin console?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm still relatively new to programming, Django, and creating apps so please bear with me. I'm working on a dietary app and I'm having a hard time visualizing and understanding why my specific use case of a `ManyToManyField` for one of my models is not showing up in the admin console. I tried reading the Django docs for the `ManyToManyField` relationship but I am still having troubles understanding it, so hopefully someone can explain this to me like I am a happy golden retriever.

I have three models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Product name', max_length=100)
   product_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Product description', max_length=500)
   product_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
          return self.product_name
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class Recipe(models.Model):
   recipe_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Recipe name', max_length=100)
   ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='Ingredients', through='IngredientQuantity', through_fields=('recipe','ingredient'))
   
   class Meta:
          ordering = ['recipe_name']

   def __str__(self):
          return self.recipe_name   

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class IngredientQuantity(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Quantity', decimal_places=2, max_digits=99, null=False)
```

What I was trying to do with this was create an Intermediary with `IngredientQuantity` which will give me the quantity along with a selected `Product` that I can then associate with `Recipe`.

However I am not seeing the `ingredients` input for `Recipe` when I attempt to create a new entry for `Recipe` in the Django admin console, is this supposed to be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app **admin.py** file add these lines:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Product, Recipe, IngredientQuantity

admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Recipe)
admin.site.register(IngredientQuantity)
```

Then you should see your models in your admin interface.